# template <typename p> is not giving error but and template <class p> is giving error

Tags: c++

while using `template <typename p>` in my program its not giving any compilation error but i use `template  <class p>` is giving error while i am passing two vector of different types.

```
template <class p>

getvector(std::vector<p>&vec)
{
// my operation
}
```

this is the function which will receive the vector , i am using the `template <typename p>` it not giving compilation error. can any body explain what makes if differ from `template <typename p >`

Comment: In this scenario, there is no difference between `typename` and `class`. Your code should pass the compilation. You can provide more detail of the error message.

Comment: In both cases function needs to have return type specified. Try `template <typename p> void getvector(...) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the `typename` and a `class` in function [template declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template). When declaring a template parameter they mean the same thing. Your function needs a return type:

```
template <class p>
std::vector<p> getvector(std::vector<p> &vec)
{
    // your code
    return vec;
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
template <typename p>
std::vector<p> getvector(std::vector<p> &vec)
{
    // your code
    return vec;
}
```

If you don't want to return a simple `void` function would be:

```
template <typename p> // or template <class p>
void getvector(std::vector<p> &vec)
{
    std::cout << vec[0]; // your code here
}
```